# CSS not selecting child elements correctly

Tags: css

This CSS style applies to links inside a table which the class property is not set,

```
.gridpager a:link, a:active, a:visited, a:hover
{
    color: #77A22E;
}
```

[image]

I need to set color of child links only which are inside the sections which the class property is `gridpager`

What am I missing here?

Comment: where have you applied the `gridpager` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `.gridpager` selector on each item in your list:

```
.gridpager a:link, .gridpager a:active, .gridpager a:visited, .gridpager a:hover
{
    color: #77A22E;
}
```

(Each item in the list is an independent selector—you have to start from scratch after each comma.)

Answer (score 2):

The selector is wrong. It should be

```
.gridpager a:link, 
.gridpager a:active, 
.gridpager a:visited, 
.gridpager a:hover
{
    color: #77A22E;
}
```